How to VLAN tags for virtual machines with Open vSwitch, the internet is not connected
I installed the OVS package and created a bridge. When I connect the VM to that bridge, the internet works within the virtual machine. For example, I want to use VLAN tags like 100 and 200 within each of the two virtual machines. However, after specifying the tag and setting the VLAN tag in the libvirt XML, the internet does not work within the virtual machine, and the IP address is not assigned. I couldn't find a solution in the documentation. I want to know how to set up a virtual machine with VLAN after specifying the tag. Thank you.
Below is the current OVS configuration.
[host ~]# ovs-vsctl show
    Bridge ovsbr0
        Port eno1
            tag: 0
            Interface eno1
        Port ovsbr0
            Interface ovsbr0
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.17.10"

2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 
12: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 
13: ovsbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 
    inet 192.168.10.20/24 scope global ovsbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='mac'/>
  <source bridge='ovsbr0'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>


Specify VLAN tag in libvirt XML
Assign a tag to the Ethernet port connected to the OVS bridge
Connect VLAN 100 and 200 to each of the two virtual machines
I expected that each virtual machine would be able to connect to the internet, and since the VLAN tag numbers are different, they wouldn't be able to ping each other. However, the virtual machines cannot connect to the internet. If I connect the virtual machines to the OVS bridge without specifying a tag, the internet works normally.


It sounds like you have no idea at all how VLAN actually work but just assumptions that it can help achieve your goal, while it's probably irrelevant / inappropriate when you are using bridged networking and seemingly a (home?) router/switch that doesn't support VLAN.

Marke sure your OVS bridge (ovsbr0) and the physical interface (eno1) are correctly set up. You need to create additional OVS ports for each VLAN.
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br ovsbr0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 eno1

Add tagged ports for each VLAN:
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vlan100 tag=100 -- set Interface vlan100 type=internal
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vlan200 tag=200 -- set Interface vlan200 type=internal

Configure the physical interface (eno1) to trunk mode to allow VLAN traffic:
sudo ovs-vsctl set port eno1 trunks=100,200

Assign IP addresses to the VLAN interfaces if required (for example, for routing or gateway purposes):
sudo ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev vlan100
sudo ip addr add 192.168.200.1/24 dev vlan200
sudo ip link set vlan100 up
sudo ip link set vlan200 up

Edit the libvirt XML configuration for each VM to use the OVS bridge and specify the VLAN tag. For example, for a VM using VLAN 100:
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='mac'/>
  <source bridge='ovsbr0'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'>
    <parameters interfaceid='vlan100'/>
  </virtualport>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <vlan>
    <tag id='100'/>
  </vlan>
</interface>

Similarly, for a VM using VLAN 200:
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='mac'/>
  <source bridge='ovsbr0'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'>
    <parameters interfaceid='vlan200'/>
  </virtualport>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <vlan>
    <tag id='200'/>
  </vlan>
</interface>

Restart the networking service to apply the changes:
sudo systemctl restart networking

Reboot the VMs or re-apply the libvirt configurations:
sudo virsh define /path/to/your/vm1.xml
sudo virsh define /path/to/your/vm2.xml
sudo virsh start vm1
sudo virsh start vm2

Inside each VM, verify that the VLAN configuration is applied correctly and that the VM can obtain an IP address from the respective VLAN network.
ip addr show

Then, verify that the VMs can reach the internet and are isolated from each other based on their VLAN tags.
Good luck!
